# How to Provide Unity Desktop Integration Features to Site on Chromium

Tags: unity, firefox, chromium

I have installed firefox and chromium browser, both are working well, but i am constantly using chromium, still it's not supported to Unity Desktop Integration, default firefox having unity integration, facebook, twitter and youtube and other account get on firefox, but how i get it for my chromium browser integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install the extension and make Chromium default browser:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-chromium-extension
```